# Terraform bitbucket pipeline artifacts

Tags: terraform, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to dpeloy terraform with bitbucket pipelines and everything works up to the apply stage.
On apply step I'm getting this error:
`

```
terraform apply -auto-approve output-${ENVIRONMENT}.plan

Error: Failed to load "output-development.plan" as a plan file

Error: stat output-development.plan: no such file or directory
```

How can I transfer the artifact to the apply stage so bitbucket can read it and proceed with the apply step?

This is my pipeline
image: hashicorp/terraform

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &pre-deploy
        name: Initilize the terraform environment
        script:
          - terraform init -backend-config ${ENVIRONMENT}-backend.tfvars
          - terraform validate
          - terraform plan -var-file=${ENVIRONMENT}.tfvars -out output-${ENVIRONMENT}.plan
        artifacts:
          - output-${ENVIRONMENT}.plan
    - step: &terraform-apply
        name: Deploy terraform code
        script:
          - terraform apply -auto-approve output-${ENVIRONMENT}.plan

pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step: 
          <<: *pre-deploy
          deployment: terraform-prepare
      - step: 
          <<: *terraform-apply
          trigger: manual
          deployment: terraform-deploy
```

Comment: Using variables in artifacts is not supported https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-21666. Using `output-*.plan` should work instead

Comment: @Randommm Thanks much
This is the correct answer, and that was my issue, using variables in artifacts is not able
Just as a not for the others that will come across this answer:
After removing the variable in the artifacts name my pipeline failed with `registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws: there is no package for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws 4.8.0 cached in .terraform/providers`
And I have to add `- .terraform/**` in my artifacts.
And after adding this to the artifacts, the pipeline tries to upload .terraform and it takes more time?
Do you have another better aporach of doing this?

Comment: You can run whatever command from the first step that makes the cache in the deploy step to skip adding it to the artifacts, tho if it is something you dont often go change you can cache it https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-dependencies/

Comment: Every single terraform step should start with a `terraform init` instruction, regardless of the availability of the .terraform cache. Quoting the docs: "Remember that caches are temporary, so your builds should be configured to work whether or not the cache is present."